# Send string from textbox together with file into Flask

Tags: python, forms, flask, jinja2

With flask I'm rendering html page on which I need to uplad file and alongside get text string for processing together with document.
First part with importing and parsing document working perfectly. But I could not manage to import file and read text box at the same time in one request.
Is it possible?

My app.py:

```
# route and function to handle the upload page
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_page():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if there is a file in the request
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            return render_template('upload.html', msg='No file selected')
        file = request.files['file']
        # if no file is selected
        if file.filename == '':
            return render_template('upload.html', msg='No file selected')
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
            file.save(path)

            # text input:
            text = request.form['text']
            processed_text = text
            print(text)

            # perform analysis on it
```

My upload.html:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Upload Docx</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  
   <h1>Upload new File</h1>
  
   <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
     <p><input type=file name=file>
        <input type=submit value=Upload>
   </form>

    <form method=post>
        <input name="text">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>


   {% if msg %}
   <h1><p style="color:blue";>{{ msg }} </p></h1>
   {% endif %}

   {% if file_name %}
     <p>  Imported document: <b> {{file_name}} </b> </p> 
   {% endif %}
   
   <h1>Result:</h1>
   
   
   {% if d_type %}
     <p> I. Type of document: <b> {{ d_type }} </b> </p>
   {% else %}
     The analysis result will be displayed here.
   {% endif %}
  

 </body>
</html>
```

So, what I need is to have textbox, which will be read when user press upload file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems I've found a solution - move textbox in one form with upload. Dont know is it legal, but seems it's working)

Replace this:

```
   <h1>Upload new File</h1>
  
   <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
     <p><input type=file name=file>
        <input type=submit value=Upload>
   </form>

    <form method=post>
        <input name="text">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

to this:

```
  
   <h1>Upload new File</h1>
  
   <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
     <p><input type=file name=file>
        <input name="text">
        <input type=submit value=Upload>
   </form>
```

Comment: That's very much legal. This is the proper way! Great work solving your own problem :)